# How can I share session(cookies) between subdomains with different Top Level Domain(tld) length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

I have a saas based application with faye server integration.

Each tenant has its own subdomain and own database on different servers.

I want to share session cookies between `xyz.mydomain.com` and `connect.xyz.mydomain.com`.

I tried `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_my_key', :domain => "mydomain.com", :tld_length => 2` But it does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_Key', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```